# Making title page with an article class

Tags: titles

How can I make an article title page that I can customise as I wish rather than using

```
\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\author{Fran}
```

in

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\author{Fran}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text

\end{document}
```

I could redefine `\maketitle` of make a new command such as

```
\keys_define:nn { title_keys }
 {
  title .tl_set:N = \l_title_tl,
  author .tl_set:N = \l_author_tl,
  date .tl_set:N = \l_date_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketitlepage}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { title_keys } { #1 }
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \centering
  {\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath \l_title_tl \par}
  \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
  {
   \large\lineskip .5em 
   \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
     \l_author_tl
   \end{tabular}\par
  }
  \vspace{1em}
  {\large\l_date_tl}
  \par\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
 }
```

Comment: use the titlepage environment or (usually better) define \maketitle with the layout that you wish using the data stored in `\@title` etc

Comment: You are searching environment `titlepage` or [package `uni-titlepage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-titlepage) or [package `titling`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) …

Comment: If I want to have the possibility of selecting among different page layouts, would it be better to keep  `\maketitle` intact and not mess with it ?  In this way, users cam still use the default behaviour for the class,